# Using uglify and minify with if condition in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to minify and uglify all the ***.js** files in a folder and push the result to another folder using **Gulp** based on a certain condition, like if I pass the **env** parameter as **prod** then only this should happen as in:

Here is my **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp                    = require('gulp');
var gminify                 = require('gulp-minify');
var gif                     = require('gulp-if');
var guglify                 = require('gulp-uglify');
var args                    = require('yargs').argv;


gulp.task('minify_js', function(){
    return gulp
            .src('app/js/*.js')//TAKE ALL THE JS FILES FROM THE FOLDER  
            .pipe(gif(args.env === "prod", gminify()))//DO MINIFY ONLY IN CASE env === prod
            .pipe(gif(args.env === "prod", guglify()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));//PASTES THEM TO dist/js folder after processing
});
```

Now for running this I am using like this:

```
gulp minify_js --env prod
```

In this case whenever I give **--env** value as **prod** the minified version gets generated which is ok but it is not in **uglify** format.

Also just **for the reference** there is a **js** file inside of **app/js** named **test.js** and its content is as follows:

```
var abc = function(){
   console.log("This is just a test message");
};
abc();
```

After running, 2 files gets generated inside of **dist/js** namely **test.js** (whose content is same) and **tests.min.js** whose content is like this:

```
var abc=function(){console.log("This is just a test message")};abc();
```

which looks like **minified** but not the **uglified**.

So my question is what I missed?

***FYI:*** I already installed **gulp, gulp-minify, gulp-if, gulp-uglify, yargs** as development dependencies.

Comment: are you sure that you need minify, if you are already do uglify? And are you sure, that gulp uglify result will be different from minify?

Comment: I mean,  try to call it with uglify only, and check result. In my case it return minified-uglified file. My config - `.pipe(source(output))
        .pipe(gulpif(Profile.environment === 'prod', streamify(uglify())))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(projectJsFolder))`

Comment: Actually I tried by removing the minify call and the result is just the minified file not the  uglified one. I mean the content of just the uglify case is also same as `tests.min.js` but the name was `tests.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments, I can do conclusion, that you have incorrect understanding of minification and uglification. Here is small example:

Not minified and not uglified example:

```
/**
 * This class describe animal class
 *
 */
class Animal(name) {
  this.name = name !== false ? name : "animal";
}
function wrapName(name) {
  var length = name.length;
  return length < 5 ? "My name: " + name : name;
}
```

here is minified example:

```
class Animal(name){this.name=name!==false?name:"animal";}function wrapName(name){var length=name.length;return length<5?"My name: "+name:name;}
```

And here is uglified example:

```
class Animal(n){this.name=!!n?n:"animal";}function wrapName(n){return n.length<5?"My name: "+n:n;}
```

As you see, uglified and minified examples look like quite similar. Only difference that uglify will (can) rename some block-scoped variables (such as  function argumens) to one letter, or do some replacements such as `false`→`!1`, `true`→`!0`.

Implementation of minification can be different from one library to another library, and possibly you are using same function calls twice, but with different names.

Comment: Thanks for that, so what should I do to make the code unreadable. I mean which plugin to use for that.

Comment: I can advice to do uglify action only.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.